# Why does to_be_bytes() and to_le_bytes() do the opposite of what I expect here?

Tags: rust, endianness, bytebuffer

Maybe the question should be "Why do I expect to_be_bytes() and to_le_bytes() to do the opposite here?", but anyways, here is the situation:

```rust
fn main() {
    let buf: [u8; 2048] // Buffer I use to receive UDP messages

    let (_, entry, _) = unsafe { buf[14..].align_to::<u16>() };
    // In memory entry looks like: 00 44 16 15   21 04 03 5a   03 67 03 6a   03 64 88 91

    let [first, second] = entry[0].to_be_bytes();
    
    assert_eq!(first, 0x44);
    assert_eq!(second, 0x00);
}
```

Shouldn't it be the opposite? Isn't big endianness like preserving the order in memory?

Comment: `to_be_bytes()` on a little endian system will swap the bytes around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big endian means the high byte is stored (or transmitted) first, meaning at the lowest address. Intel processors are little endian, meaning the low byte is stored in the low address.

There are some advantages to each, but generally big endian is preferred, which is why network protocols and portable data formats are usually big endian. Intel remains little endian for compatibility with older versions. Some CPUs have modes that can switch between the two, but Intel never did that.

Comment: If my system is little endian (has an Intel CPU) then why do I see everything as big endian in memory? That 16 in memory is a real 16 that was sent to me (in BCD), for example. Also, in my example, if I want `first` to be`0x00` consistently across devices, do I have to use to_ne_bytes()?

Comment: @Blue You're looking at a chunk of raw bytes. Of course the bytes will be in the same order you received them. It's only when you *interpret* those bytes as something *larger than a byte* that endianness comes into play. If you only look at the data byte by byte it will look the same on every architecture.

Comment: `align_to` will group `0x00 0x44` in native format, which for Intel is low byte first, high byte second = `0x4400`. `to_be_bytes` will extract the high (big end) byte (`0x44`) first, then low byte (`0x00`). You might want to get the byte order the way you want it for your architecture before converting to `u16`.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to know exactly what your expectations go wrong but I'll try to explain what's happening here.

When you do `buf.align_to()` there is no transformation being done, the bytes are reinterpretted as-is. So `entry[0]` (assuming it *was* aligned) will be stored as `00 44` in memory. Your system is likely a little endian architecture, so the *value* of `entry[0]` is `17408`.

```
fn main() {
    let buf = [0x00, 0x44];
    let result = u16::from_ne_bytes(buf); // also doesn't try to reinterpret bytes
    assert_eq!(result, 17408);
}
```

So now, `entry[0]` is a `u16` on a little endian system representing the value `17408`. To get the same value with a big-endian representation, as `to_be_bytes()` does, it will swap the bytes around.

---

Given your use case of network communication where its common for values to be encoded in big endian order, you probably want to use `entry[0].from_be()` to get the proper value of `68`.

Comment: I'm not using _from_ functions. I'm using _to_ functions.

Comment: I'll answer a different way... If you want `[first, second]` to always match the byte order of `entry[0]` which matches the byte order from the buffer, use `to_ne_bytes()`.